# Do I require an entry permit for Croatia, when applying for Schengen Visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, croatia

I am an Indian national, and am planning to visit France, Croatia, and Czech Republic, in that order.

Now, I understand that Schengen Visa is applicable for Croatia as well, even through Croatia is not part of the Schengen area. Since I will be spending almost equal amount of time in France and Czech Republic, I am planning to apply for a Uniform Schengen Visa (Multiple Entry) from France's embassy (via the authorized service provider, VFS global).

The Schengen visa application form asks about the "Entry permit for the final country of destination, where applicable". I have two questions:

1. What is my "final country of destination"? From India, I am traveling to Paris (in Schengen area); from Paris, I am going to Croatia (outside Schengen area); from there, I am traveling to Prague (within Schengen), and finally to India (my nation) from Prague.
   Since Croatia lies outside the Schengen area, will that be my "final country of destination", or will it be India?
2. If Croatia is my final country of destination, and if Croatia accepts Schengen visa, how would it be possible for me to enter visa details (i.e., entry permit) for Croatia in the corresponding entry mentioned above in the application form for Schengen visa? Do I need to get a visa for Croatia as well?

Kindly help me clarify the doubt.

Comment: IMO the key word is "Where applicable". You can skip this section as it is not apllicable to you. Mention your itinerary in the civer letter and apply for multiple entry visa.

Comment: @RedBaron make into an answer?